# AppDomain await async Task prevent SerializationException

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, appdomain

I have a windows service, which loads assembly in another AppDomain at runtime. Then it executes them and finally unloads the AppDomain. The problem is the execute method from the plugins are async tasks and I get the SerializationException because Task does not inherit from MarshalByRefObject.

I wrapped the plugin in a proxy which inherits from MarshalByRefObject, but I dont know how to get rid of the SerializationException?

```
public interface IPlugin : IDisposable
{
    Guid GUID { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    Task Execute(PluginPanel panel, string user);
}
```

The proxy:

```
[Serializable()]
public class PluginProxy : MarshalByRefObject, IPlugin
{
    private IPlugin m_Plugin;

    public bool Init(string file)
    {
        Assembly ass = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file));
        if (ass == null || ass.GetTypes() == null || ass.GetTypes().Length == 0)
            return false;
        foreach (Type type in ass.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsInterface || type.IsAbstract)
                continue;
            if (type.GetInterface(typeof(IPlugin).FullName) != null)
            {
                m_Plugin = (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public Guid GUID { get { return m_Plugin.GUID; } }
    public string Name { get { return m_Plugin.Name; } }
    public string Description { get { return m_Plugin.Description; } }
    // I debugged and found out the error happens AFTER m_Plugin.Execute
    // so the method runs well, but the return back to the pProxy.Execute is throwing the SerializationException       
    public async Task Execute(PluginPanel panel, string user) { await m_Plugin.Execute(panel, user); }
}
```

And the Method which loads the Assembly and gets the SerializationException:

```
        AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
        // some setup stuff

        AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), null, setup);
        PluginProxy pProxy = (PluginProxy)dom.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase, typeof(PluginProxy).FullName);
        pProxy.Init(app.Apppath);
        // I await the task later in code, because the user can cancel the execution
        try { tExe = pProxy.Execute(panel, user.Username); }
           catch (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException e)
           {
               // runs always in this catch, even if no Exception from the plugin was thrown
           }
           catch (Exception e) { AddToErrorLog(panel.PanelName, e); }
           finally
           {
               pProxy.Dispose();
               AppDomain.Unload(dom);
           }
```

Maybe my whole concept of loading Plugins is wrong?

Comment: Your `Execute` also returns the `Task`. In your wrapper wait for `Execute` synchronously .

Comment: so instead of await m_Plugin.Execute(panel, user); I should do this: m_Plugin.Execute(panel, user);? Or this: m_Plugin.Execute(panel, user).Wait();? But the Wait() would block the whole thread?

Comment: OK, look at the Stephen Toub [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/28277f25-5f5d-4b7c-bf1f-402937fc9f31/tasks-across-appdomain). You should make little changes for your case.

Comment: Thank you, I looked into the post, but there is nothing with async? He creates a static Task<string> method which returns a Task<string>. But I need an async method, so I can await it and I cant return something in an async Task method. 
I am new to the whole async thing, so maybe I am just overlooking something.

Comment: You can await for Task returned by `DoWorkInOtherDomain`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Hamlet Hakobyan and the post from Stephen Toub, I think I was able to solve the problem.

I replaced the line from the caller

```
 try { tExe = pProxy.Execute(panel, user.Username); }
```

with

```
 tExe = DoWorkInOtherDomain(pProxy, panel, user.Username);
```

and the method DoWorkInOtherDomain:

```
private Task DoWorkInOtherDomain(PluginProxy pProxy, PluginPanel panel, string user)
    {
        var ch = new MarshaledResultSetter<string>();
        pProxy.Execute(panel, user, ch);
        return ch.Task;
    }
```

and finally the proxy class:

```
 Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                m_Plugin.Execute(panel, user).Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                if (e.InnerExceptions != null)
                    foreach (Exception ein in e.InnerExceptions)
                        AddToErrorLog(panel.PanelName, ein);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { AddToErrorLog(panel.PanelName, e); }
            finally { ch.SetResult(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName); }
        });
```

I need to call Wait() in

```
m_Plugin.Execute(panel, user).Wait();
```

it catches the Exceptions from the plugin so everything is doing fine. The Wait() call should only blocking the Task.Run and not the other Tasks.

Can anyone tell me if this is a good solution or should I change something? I dont need a result so I just do:

```
 ch.SetResult(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
```

because I dont know how I should do it without a result.

Comment: The only probem I have now is that I cant catch Exceptions from the plugins. Even if I throw one, `m_Plugin.Execute(panel, user);` does not catches it. If the `Execute` method throws an Exception and neither `m_Plugin.Execute(panel, user);` nor `await m_Plugin.Execute(panel, user);` in 'PluginProxy' catches the `Exception`, where is it going? Shouldnt the application be crashing if an unhandled Exception is thrown?