# Load assembly in async Task asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I run async Task which uses code from referenced DLL. In this case I cat error message that this referenced DLL can not be found.

```
Message: Unable to find assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.

    StackTrace:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap.Create(String name, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.AppDomain.Deserialize(Byte[] blob)
   at System.AppDomain.UnmarshalObject(Byte[] blob)
```

If the code is in async Task then DLLs are taken from different location? Should I install it to GAC?

This is my web.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

In Bin folder I have a Newtonsoft.Json.Dll, I run powershell script to check what is the version and it is:

```
[Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName('MyLocation\Newtonsoft.Json.DLL').Version
```

And the result is:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
8      0      0      0
```

Then I wanted to check which assemblies are loaded into w3wp.exe process using [listDlls.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls) and there is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\xxx\Newtonsoft.Json.DLL
```

So I navigated there copied the dll and checked the version (just to be sure) and it is 8.0.0.0

I'm not sure what else can I do :D

Comment: Could you show some of your code?

Comment: You must post some code you are using. Right now it is hard to tell, where is the problem

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with the code being in an async task. More likely you have different dependencies that require different versions of JSON.NET, and your bindings are strict enough that your app won't accept the version that ends up in your bin folder.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I just edited the question

Comment: @JustinHui Sure, done

Comment: @Snorlax: Have you gone through the suggestions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027543/visual-studio-2012-web-api-project-wont-run-cant-find-newtonsoft-json)?

Comment: The error is in your developer environment or in the server?. You have to ensure this DLL have to be in your Bin directory and no other in the moment of compilation. Read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

Comment: The error is on server, locally it works fine

Answer (score 0):

> I see that this is a cross domain serailization exception coming from
>   [CrossAppDomainSerializer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/crossappdomainchannel.cs) and this is used as Remoting
>   Infrastructure Sink for making calls across context boundaries

This is an issue originating from your code and remoting is done,please refer this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555702/appdomain-await-async-task-prevent-serializationexception) .

Hope this helps!